# EGit: how to create a new tag?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'd like to create a new tag using EGit. According to [the manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Tag) there are two ways of doing it:

1. Select **Team** > **Advanced** > **Tag...**

   - But I don't have the **Advanced** sub-menu in the **Team** menu.
2. Execute **Create Tag...** on a commit in the History view.

   - But I don't have this button/option in the History view.

How do I do it? Thank you.

My setup:

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
Eclipse EGit 3.0.1.201307141637-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tip at the [Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1078106/#msg_1078106) showed how:

1. Switch to Git Repository Perspective;
2. Check out the local branch to tag into the Git Repositories View;
3. In the project tree right click on Tags -> Create Tag
4. Enter tag name and tag message.

After this the tag must be pushed to the remote repository, but that is something that can be made in the regular coding perspective.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Juno as well and I have the Team->Advanced->Tag menu in the context menu of the project.
(Right click on the project connected to the GIT)

After creting the tag V.01 for instance, you need to Push the tag to the repository.

In the Git Repositories view, you have the Tags under you project. In the context menu of your tag you have the Push Tag menu.

Target Ref Name: should be something like refs/tags/V0.1
(without refs/tags/ path you will get an error "funny refname" )